# Reading .exr files in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, zbuffer, openexr

I have generated some depth maps using blender and have saved z-buffer values(32 bits) in OpenEXR format. Is there any way to access values from a .exr file (pixel by pixel depth info) using OpenCV 2.4.13 and python 2.7? There is no example anywhere to be found. All I can see in documentation that this file format is supported. But trying to read such a file results in error.

```
new=cv2.imread("D:\\Test1\\0001.exr")
cv2.imshow('exr',new)
print new[0,0]
```

Error:

```
print new[0,0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

and

```
cv2.imshow('exr',new)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Closest I found is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2119099/6677891) and this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/70643/imread-imshow-openexr-example/).

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413604/how-to-load-a-many-channel-exr-in-android)

Comment: I also found this http://excamera.com/articles/26/doc/index.html just now. (:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using EXR images in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119099/using-exr-images-in-opencv)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I might be a little late to the party but; 
Yes you can definitely use OpenCV for that.

```
cv2.imread(PATH_TO_EXR_FILE,  cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

should get you what you need

Comment: In C++: `cv::imread(PATH_TO_EXR_FILE, cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);`

Answer (score 4):

## Full solution

@Iwohlhart's solution threw an error for me and following fixed it,

```py
# first import os and enable the necessary flags to avoid cv2 errors

import os
os.environ["OPENCV_IO_ENABLE_OPENEXR"]="1"
import cv2

# then just type in following

img = cv2.imread(PATH2EXR, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
'''
you might have to disable following flags, if you are reading a semantic map/label then because it will convert it into binary map so check both lines and see what you need
''' 
# img = cv2.imread(PATH2EXR) 
 
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OpenEXR](https://github.com/jamesbowman/openexrpython/issues/28#issuecomment-522317986) package

```
pip --no-cache-dir install OpenEXR
```

If the above fails, install the OpenEXR dev library and then install the python package as above

```
sudo apt-get install openexr
sudo apt-get install libopenexr-dev
```

If gcc is not installed

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install g++
```

To read exr file

```
def read_depth_exr_file(filepath: Path):
    exrfile = exr.InputFile(filepath.as_posix())
    raw_bytes = exrfile.channel('B', Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT))
    depth_vector = numpy.frombuffer(raw_bytes, dtype=numpy.float32)
    height = exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].max.y + 1 - exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].min.y
    width = exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].max.x + 1 - exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].min.x
    depth_map = numpy.reshape(depth_vector, (height, width))
    return depth_map
```