# Read, process and show the pixels in .EXR format images

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, openexr, hdrimages

I want to read the exr file format images and see the pixel intensities in the corresponding location. And also wanted to stack them together to give them into a neural network. How can I do the normal image processing on these kind of formats? Please help me in doing this!

I have tried this code using OpenEXR file but unable to proceed further.

```
import OpenEXR
file = OpenEXR.InputFile('file_name.exr')
```

I am expected to see the normal image processing tools like

```
file.size()
file.show()
file.write('another format')
file.min()
file.extract_channels()
file.append('another exr file')
```

Comment: Also check answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44630793/3337089)

Answer (score 4):

OpenEXR seems to be lacking the fancy image processing features such as displaying images or saving the image to a different format. For this I would suggest you using `OpenCV`, which is full of image processing features.

What you may need to do is:

- Read `exr` using `OpenEXR` only, then extract channels and convert them to numpy arrays as `rCh = np.asarray(rCh, dtype=np.uint8)`
- Create a RGB image from these numpy arrays as `img_rgb = cv2.merge([b, g, r])`.
- Use OpenCV functions for your listed operations:

  - Size: `img_rgb.shape`
  - Show: `cv2.imshow(img_rgb)`
  - Write: `cv2.imwrite("path/to/file.jpg", img_rgb)`
  - Min: `np.min(b)`, `np.min(g)`, `np.min(r)`
  - Extract channels: `b, g, r = cv2.split(img_rgb)`

Comment: Seems a pretty sensible approach.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [example](https://www.excamera.com/sphinx/articles-openexr.html) on the OpenEXR webpage:

```
import sys
import array
import OpenEXR
import Imath

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "usage: exrnormalize.py exr-input-file exr-output-file"
    sys.exit(1)

# Open the input file
file = OpenEXR.InputFile(sys.argv[1])

# Compute the size
dw = file.header()['dataWindow']
sz = (dw.max.x - dw.min.x + 1, dw.max.y - dw.min.y + 1)

# Read the three color channels as 32-bit floats
FLOAT = Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT)
(R,G,B) = [array.array('f', file.channel(Chan, FLOAT)).tolist() for Chan in ("R", "G", "B") ]
```

After this, you should have three arrays of floating point data, one per channel. You could easily convert these to `numpy` arrays and proceed with `opencv` as user @ZdaR suggests.