# How to convert .cr3 image file to .exr image file format

Tags: python, image

I have to convert the .cr3 image file to .exr image file using python. anyone know how to convert? is there any python opensource tool is available?

TIA

I have a bunch of image files. We have available online tools but we cant use that because of data security.

Comment: [`rawpy`](https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/) can likely read in the image data, which would then likely need to be processed (debayering, etc?). Writing out an exr image may be a bit more difficult, as the project seems to have only a small team and not much active python development. [this](https://pypi.org/project/openexr-python/) package seems to be the most recent python binding (after you've installed openEXR separately)

Comment: [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630793/reading-exr-files-in-opencv) a question on reading exr, which might be applicable to writing exr as well. It would seem openCV may have some support for it...

Comment: How did you get on with my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that several ways. The simplest is with the `openimageio-tools` package and the command is:

```
oiiotool INPUT.CR3 -o OUTPUT.EXR
```

On Alpine Linux (which is where I tested under `docker`), the command to install the tools is:

```
apk update && apk add openimageio-tools
```

---

You can also do that with **ImageMagick** - subject to building and configuring with the RAW and OPENEXR delegates. The command would be:

```
magick INPUT.CR3 OUTPUT.EXR
```

---

You can run both of the above suggestions from Python using `subprocess.run()`.

---

If you really want to use Python, you can use [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) which calls **ImageMagick** libraries under the hood. That means that, if you install **ImageMagick** you will already have the tools to simply use the command-line version I suggested as option 2 above, so there will be little point writing any Python.